# How to use ILogger without dependency injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, dependency-injection, ilogger

net core project. I am using azure application insights to log. I have added below line in services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(); in my startup.cs. In controller and business layer I will get ILogger through dependency injection. But I cam up with something different. I have created ApiExceptionFilter and code looks like below.

```
public class ApiExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {  
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            ApiError apiError = null;
            if (context.Exception is ApiException)
            {
                // handle explicit 'known' API errors
                var ex = context.Exception as ApiException;
                context.Exception = null;
                apiError = new ApiError(ex.Message);

                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = ex.StatusCode;
            }
            else if (context.Exception is UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                apiError = new ApiError("Unauthorized Access");
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;

                // handle logging here
            }
            else if (context.Exception is NotImplementedException)
            {
                apiError = new ApiError("Not Implemented");
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;

                // handle logging here
            }
            else if (context.Exception is ArgumentNullException)
            {
                apiError = new ApiError(string.Format("Parameter: {0} is required, it cannot be empty", (context.Exception as ArgumentNullException).ParamName));
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;

                // handle logging here
            }
            else
            {
                // Unhandled errors
                var msg = context.Exception.GetBaseException().Message;
                string stack = context.Exception.StackTrace;
                apiError = new ApiError(msg);
                apiError.detail = stack;

                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;

                // handle logging here
            }

            // always return a JSON result
            context.Result = new JsonResult(apiError);

            base.OnException(context);
        }
    }
```

But here I cannot do something like

```
private readonly ILogger _logger;
        public ApiExceptionFilter(ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
```

If I make above changes then

```
  [ApiController]
    [ApiExceptionFilter] //here it asking for paramter ilogger
    public class MyController : ControllerBase
```

In the above code  [ApiExceptionFilter]  It will ask for me to pass ILogger parameter.

I am just wondering what is the correct way to add ILogger in ApiExceptionFilter. Can someone help me in this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Be aware that 401 is the wrong code for "not implemented" and "ArgumentNullException" exception. 401 is for unauthorized and shouldn't never be returned on other errors, since most clients will react with a login process on this (i.e. refreshing token, redirecting to login page etc).

Comment: 404 (NotFound) is more appropriiate for not implemented and you also shouldnt generically catch ArgumentNullExceptions, cause they cant come from controllers (if they would, it could be translated to 400 Bad Request), but from your Logic and it can mean anything (error in your code logic) where as code 400 Bad Request implies bad/insufficient data was sent by the client

Comment: The title of the question seems not to match with the content, tags and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your exception filter with:

```cs
[TypeFilter(typeof(ApiExceptionFilter))]
```

This will allow your filter to use services from the DI container as the framework will create the filter at request time.

E.g.

```cs
public class ApiExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public ApiExceptionFilter(ILogger logger)
    {
        // Assign the logger to a field etc.
    }
}
```

You can also use `[ServiceFilter(typeof(ApiExceptionFilter))]` and register the filter itself in the DI container.

Comment: Hi I made changes as above but When I ran app now started getting "ErrorDetail": "Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'SGRE.SiteEnrichment.WebApi.Filters.ApiExceptionFilter'.",

Comment: Hmm... Could you try injecting either ILoggerFactory or `ILogger<ApiExceptionFilter>` instead?

Comment: I added services.AddScoped<ILogger<ApiExceptionFilter>>(); but got exception when running System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[WebApi.Filters.ApiExceptionFilter]' for service type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[WebApi.Filters.ApiExceptionFilter]'.'

Comment: Normally logging is added with `services.AddLogging()` I think

Answer (score 1):

In order to use DependencyInjection in action filters you need to use TypeFilterAttribute,

Example:

```cs
public class HandleExceptionAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
        public HandleExceptionAttribute() : base(typeof(HandleExceptionPrivate))
        {
        }

        class HandleExceptionPrivate : ExceptionFilterAttribute
        {
            private readonly ILogger _logger;
            private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;
          
            public HandleExceptionPrivate(ILoggerFactory logger, IHostingEnvironment env)
            {
                _logger = logger.CreateLogger("Exeption Filter");
                _env = env;
            }

            public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
            {
                _logger.LogError(Constants.LoggingEvents.EXCEPTION, context.Exception, "message");
               
                context.ExceptionHandled = true;
                context.Exception = null;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: When I ran app now started getting  "ErrorDetail": "Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'SGRE.SiteEnrichment.WebApi.Filters.ApiExceptionFilter'.",

Comment: so Do I need to add ILoggerin startup something like this?

Comment: You should add Logger configuration in startup.     loggerFactory.AddMsSql(null, Configuration.GetConnectionString("LoggerConnection"), httpContextAccessor, applicationName: "API");    for example

Comment: Do I need to use loggerFactory? and I am not using AddMsSql

Comment: That was an example, no matter what you use for logging, just add Logger to service provider. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1